# How to list mail adresses of active users on a Linux machine?

Tags: user-accounts, passwd, shadow

I'd like to get a list of mail addresses of all users, who are allowed to login. How can I do this?

I've set mail addresses in `/etc/passwd` using the [GECOS field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field), i.e. via `sudo chfn some_user -o some_user@ourdomain.org`.

This can be [done using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/95474/859591):

```
awk -F : '{print $5}' /etc/passwd | awk -F , '{print $5}'
```

However, I would like to exclude users who's account has expired.

The user expiration information is stored in `/etc/shadow`. There is the Python module [spwd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/spwd.html), but it is deprecated and its successor does not seem to be able to check if an account is still valid.

The command `chage -l my_user` displays expiration date, but one needs root permissions for the information of other users, even if the shadow file is readable for everyone.

Is there anything else I should take care of, besides the expiration date?

Comment: `/etc/shadow` isn't supposed to be readable for everyone.

Comment: I've checked 2 different systems, Ubuntu and Pop!_OS: both seem to have read permissions set for the shadow file:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4,1K Jän 11 15:17 /etc/shadow`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549464/etc-shadow-permissions-security-best-practice-000-vs-600-vs-640

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/827608/why-is-the-file-permission-for-etc-shadow-set-to-600

Comment: If you have untrusted user accounts on your system with word-readable `/etc/shadow` you can consider accounts with weak passwords compromised.

Comment: @AlexD hm yes, I see. Thanks for the hint! No idea why permissions are set in a wrong way on two different systems. However, this is quite off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatGPT wrote a proper script for me which works better than a bash one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Print email addresses of all users on this machine.
# Email addresses are stored in the GECOS field in the of the passwd file. Accounts which are
# expired are ignored.
#
# The script might need to be run as root, depending on whether the /etc/shadow file is readable by
# your user or not.
#
# This script has been written by ChatGPT (and then fixed by a human).


set -e  # abort script on first error


is_account_expired() {
    local expire_date=$(grep "^$1:" /etc/shadow | cut -d ':' -f 8)
    local today=$(date +%s)
    if [[ -z $expire_date || $expire_date -ge $today ]]; then
        return 1  # Account is not expired
    else
        return 0  # Account is expired
    fi
}

while IFS=':' read -r username _; do
    if ! grep -q "^$username:" /etc/shadow; then
        continue  # Skip if account does not exist in shadow file
    fi
    if ! is_account_expired "$username"; then
        # Extract email from GECOS field
        email=$(getent passwd "$username" | cut -d ':' -f 5 | awk -F',' '{print $5}')
        # Print email if not expired and not empty
        if [ -n "$email" ]; then
            echo "$email"
        fi
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way which is a bit brittle, but it kinda works:

```
join -t: /etc/shadow /etc/passwd | awk -F : '$8==""{print $13}'  | awk -F , '{print $5}'
```

**Warning:** The command above might not do the correct thing for every situation!

It uses an awk command from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/95474/859591) to print out the GECOS information and combines it with join, so we can use information from passwd and shadow at the same time: lines are matched up at the first column (`-t:` specifies that `:` is used as separator), so files are matched using the user name. In the joined file, column 13 is the GECOS information, which is printed only if column 8 is empty. Column 8 contains the account expiration information.

**Pitfalls:**

- If shadow file and passwd file are not sorted the same way, some lines may be missing and a warning is printed: `join: /etc/shadow:38: is not sorted: [...]`. I haven't figured out how to fix this without temporary files: the man page of join, suggests to sort files before passing them to join, but clearly one can pass only one file using stdin, so temporary files are needed.
- Account expiration information is not really compared to today's date. It simply filters all lines where an expiration date is set. In my case, all active accounts are unlimited and never expire, the inactivated ones are set to an expiration date of 1. Therefore, the solution is good enough for me.
- We don't check for a valid login shell. Unsure if this is actually something one should do.